# SQL SERVER merge two column, combine it, and count the same

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, vb.net

I want to create a barcode by merge and combine two column.
here is my table :

```
 ID   |  Items1 |  Items2   |   BArcode
 001  |  Shirt  |  CPU      |      
 002  |  Shirt  | CPU       |         
 001  |  Shoes  | Monitor   |      
 002  |  Jacket |  Monitor  |      
 001  |  Shoes  |  CPU      |         
 002  |         | Keyboard  |      
 002  |         | Keyboard  |      
 001  |  Shirt  | Keyboard  |         
 002  |  Shirt  |           |
```

The barcode created based on ID+Item1/Items2+Count. The count get from counting how many times one ID have oredered the same item. I want it to display only the data that haven't generated a barcode, so it's when the Barcode column value is null, from the above table the Barcode is null:

```
 ID   |  Barcode       |  
 001  |  001Shirt1     |       
 002  |  002Shirt1     |          
 001  |  001Shoes1     |       
 002  |  002Jacket1    |        
 001  |  001Shoes2     |          
 001  |  001Shirt2     |          
 002  |  002Shirt2     |  
 001  |  001CPU1       |        
 002  |  002CPU1       |          
 001  |  001Monitor1   |       
 002  |  002Monitor1   |        
 001  |  001CPU2       |          
 002  |  002Keyboard1  |       
 002  |  002Keyboard2  |        
 001  |  001Keyboard1  |
```

here is my first code :

```
                Dim strcommand As String = "select [ID], ([ID] + [Items1]) 
                as Barcode from tbl_Request where [Items1] != 'null' 
                and Barcode = 'null' union select ([ID] + [Items2]) 
                from tbl_Request where [Items2] != 'Null' and Barcode = 'null'"
```

it doesn't work. it say "All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists".  on my code above I haven't implement the counting yet. does anyone know how to do it?

Thanks in advances....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this query to generate the `barcode` values:

```
;with cte as
(select id, item1 item, row_number() over (partition by id, item1 order by getdate()) rn
 from items
 where item1 is not null and barcode is null
 union
 select id, item2 item, row_number() over (partition by id, item2 order by getdate()) rn 
 from items
 where item2 is not null and barcode is null)

 select id, cast(id as varchar) + item + cast(rn as varchar) barcode
 from cte
```

If you wanted to add this to a new table, say `tbl_barcode` with columns `id` and `barcode`, you would do this:

```
;with cte as
(select id, item1 item, row_number() over (partition by id, item1 order by getdate()) rn
 from items
 where item1 is not null and barcode is null
 union
 select id, item2 item, row_number() over (partition by id, item2 order by getdate()) rn 
 from items
 where item2 is not null and barcode is null)

 insert into tbl_barcode (id, barcode)
 select id, cast(id as varchar) + item + cast(rn as varchar) barcode
 from cte
```

Comment: Dear Shree.pat18, Thank you for helping me. I tried your code and it's work. may I ask, how to insert the value into existing column. in the barcode column. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: There you are going to have a problem, because you have 9 rows in sample, but 15 rows output by this query. How do you decide which to take to fit into 9?

Comment: how about if I change the condition to put it into another table. for example, I add insert into tbl_Barcode before the syntax ;with cte...I'm sorry, I ask that without trying it first. My mentor is away at the moment, so I can't create new table on the server. I will try it after creating a new table. but, I just want to ask, is it possible to do that? Thank you.

Comment: oke.... Thanks for helping me. I will try your code later. my mentor still outside, don't know when he will be back. anyway, thanks for your help.

Comment: Dear Shree.pat18, Thanks for helping me. I tried your code and it's work nicely. Thank you very much.

Comment: Dear shree.pat18
may I ask again? if I want to take the last request date(lets say there is a column named request date in the above table), for example: if someone request a shirt on 17/04/2014, on 30/04/2014 that person request shirt again. how can I take the last request date of that person(i.e 17/04/2014). I can't use having count > 1 like finding a duplicate record ihn this problem.
Thanks in advances.

Comment: I added, select date, max(date) as [Last] before select id,,, but it say tbl_request.date doesn't have any agregate function...

Comment: Please add this as a new question since the requirement is differebt. Thanka.

Answer (score 0):

The error that you are getting is that the union join that you have created does not contain the same fields in the second select statement, as your original select statement. [SQL UNION Operator](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp), Notice that each SELECT statement within the UNION **must have the same number of columns**.

So therefore you will need to change

```
select ([ID] + [Items2])
```

to

```
select [ID], ([ID] + [Items2])
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it, but it doesn't display any value. when I remove the syntax "and Barcode = 'null'". nit return a value but not all.

Comment: it's already display a value, I change the barcode = 'null' to barcode IS NULL.. But it still return some of the record... it doesn't display the record that have the same value. Thanks.

Comment: You can't compare a field if it's null like that.
You should use IS NOT NULL.

Comment: @1lastBr3ath you're right. I already change it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @x table (ID varchar(20),Items1 VARCHAR(10),Items2 VARCHAR(10),BARCODE INT)

INSERT INTO @x
(ID,Items1,Items2,BARCODE)
VALUES ('001','Shirt','CPU',NULL)
INSERT INTO @x
(ID,Items1,Items2,BARCODE)
VALUES ('001',NULL,'Monitor',NULL)
INSERT INTO @x
(ID,Items1,Items2,BARCODE)
VALUES ('002','TRouser','Monitor',NULL)

select ID,
Case when Items1 IS NOT NULL Then ID +Items1+
CAST(DENSE_RANK()OVER(PARTITION by Items1  order by Items1 desc)AS VARCHAR)
when Items2 IS NOT NULL Then ID +Items2+
CAST(DENSE_RANK()OVER(PARTITION by Items2  order by Items1 desc)AS VARCHAR)
 ELSE '' END AS Barcode from @x
```

Comment: dear Mohan, I tried your code, but it's only display several data. Thanks for your help, the problem has been solved.